# Sorting before comparing two list

Tags: python, list, sorting

Well i am unable to comprehend this misbehavior by python.

I wrote a code for checking the no of combinations in the two arrays whose  difference is less than or equal to 1 .

Every element can only be used once.

c list is for storing the combinations for better understanding.

```
for k in range(0,len(bs)):
    c.append([])
    for l in range(0,len(gs)) :
       if abs(bs[k]-gs[l])<=1 and bs[k]!=-1000 and gs[l]!=-1000:
           c[k].append(bs[k])
           c[k].append(gs[l])
           bs[k]=-1000
           gs[l]=-1000
           count+=1
```

For some inputs (large inputs) it misses out on a few combinations, but when i sort the arrays  before comparison it produces accurate results.
After all its a computer and it shouldn't miss combination if the code is correct which i feel it is.

Sample input:

4 1 1 1 3 3 2 5 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 6 1 3 1 1 1 1 2 4 1 1 4 2 2 8 2 2 1 8 2 4 3 3 8 1 3 2 3 2 1 3 8 2 2 3 1 1 2 2 5 1 4 3 1 1 3 1 3 1 7 1 1 1 3 2 1 2 2 3 7 2 1 4 3 2 1 1 3 4 1 1 3 5 1 8 4 1 1 1 3 10 2 2 1 2

1 1 5 2 13 2 2 3 6 12 1 13 8 1 1 16 1 1 5 6 2 4 6 4 2 7 4 1 7 3 3 9 5 3 1 7 4 1 6 6 8 2 2 5 2 3 16 3 6 3 8 6 1 8 1 2 6 5 3 4 11 3 4 8 2 13 2 5 2 7 3 3 1 8 1 4 4 2 4 7 7 1 5 7 6 3 6 9 1 1 1 3 1 11 5 2 5 11 13 1

without sort output:74
with sort output:76

combinations without sort: i.e 74
[[4, 5], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2], [3, 2], [3, 2], [2, 3], [5, 6], [1, 1], [2, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 2], [6, 5], [1, 1], [3, 4], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 4], [1, 2], [1, 1], [4, 4], [2, 3], [2, 3], [8, 8], [2, 3], [2, 3], [1, 1], [8, 7], [2, 3], [4, 5], [3, 4], [3, 2], [8, 7], [1, 2], [3, 3], [2, 3], [3, 4], [2, 2], [1, 2], [3, 4], [8, 9], [2, 3], [2, 3], [3, 4], [1, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2], [2, 1], [5, 6], [1, 1], [4, 5], [3, 4], [1, 1], [1, 1], [3, 4], [1, 1], [3, 3], [1, 2], [7, 6], [1, 1], [], [], [3, 3], [], [], [], [], [], [7, 7], [], [], [4, 5], [], [], [], [], [], [4, 5], [], [], [], [5, 6], [], [8, 8], [4, 5], [], [], [], [], [10, 11], [], [], [], []]

combinations with sort : i.e 76
[[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [], [], [], [], [], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 4], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [4, 5], [4, 5], [4, 5], [4, 5], [4, 5], [4, 5], [4, 5], [4, 5], [5, 5], [5, 6], [5, 6], [6, 6], [7, 6], [7, 6], [8, 7], [8, 7], [8, 7], [8, 7], [8, 7], [10, 9]]

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Don't you need a tab in line 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of your algorithm depends on the order in which the elements are presented. For example, it breaks down on:

```
bs = [2, 4]
gs = [3, 1]
```

What happens here is that the 2 grabs the 3, resulting in only one match.

If, on the other hand, the 2 were matched with with the 1, then the 3 could be matched with 4, giving two matches.

Sorting takes care of this at least to some extent, making sure that the smallest suitable numbers are used first. It is not completely obvious to me that this is enough to guarantee optimality (though it likely is); that would need a bit more thought.

Comment: Well this was pretty appropriate answer , Thanks .Also it would be of great help if you could tell wheather my question was rightly framed or not ,cause i am new to SO and need to improve a lot. Some reviews would help a lot.

Comment: @KshitijDhyani: I think your question is perfectly fine, perhaps except for the assumption that the code is correct and the computer isn't executing it properly. :) This does happen but *extremely* rarely, so rarely that in the normal course of events it's not something we expect or have to deal with.

Comment: Thanks buddy , you were of great help, yes i wont make that assumption in the future .

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the standard debugging technique: make the lists smaller and smaller, while making sure the output is still unexpected.

It is possible to reproduce this unexpected behavior with lists of size 2.

Compare [2,1] with [2,3].

Also, run your algorithm manually, using pen and paper. Be sure that you follow the algorithm exactly. And if you want to do something different, find out why and in which situations.

Comment: Yes you are correct i cross checked it, but it still doesn't answer my doubt. Why this unexpected behavior ?